# Android ImageButton crops on resize

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created some custom buttons for my application. I do not want to create loads of different image sizes for the same image for screen optimisation. I am tring to scale down the  image in XML but when I change the parameters to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/one_default" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I am presented with:

[image]

The original looks like:

[image]

How can I scale down the image without the image becoming cropped?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:maxHeight="100dp"
android:maxWidth="100dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

That will work, I just tried ;)