# How to remove padding from circular progressbar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a circular ProgressBar where I want to place an image inside as shown in the screenshot, the circular progress bar have a default padding I guess ,So I need to remove it so both will have the same dimensions :

[image]

here is the code for the layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dikritem"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="@null"
        android:paddingTop="@null"
        android:paddingEnd="@null"
        android:paddingBottom="@null"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circlebackg"


        />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingStart="@null"
        android:paddingTop="@null"
        android:paddingEnd="@null"
        android:paddingBottom="@null"
        android:progress="80"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle"

        />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/tasbih_circ_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/adkarbackground"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/border"
        app:civ_border_width="0dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tasbih_circ_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tasbih_plus"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/adkarbackground"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/adkarbackground"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="40sp"


            />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/adkarbackground"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="40dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

is there any solution to remove the default padding ??

Comment: Have you tried `padding=0`?

Comment: yes bro , it changed nothing

Answer (score 5):

Using the current `com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator` you can set `app:indicatorInset="0dp"` allowing you, for instance, to set a full circle as background which borders will match exactly with the progress indicator itself.

Comment: Not doing anything

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make your view little bigger than
Try Using Negative Padding like   or try using scalex and scaley but use values greater than 1 in scale values. It will increase the scale of the view inside.

```
android:padding="-10dp"

android:scaleX="1.2"
```

Comment: no bro I want the Image text to be inside the circular progress bar , and for that I 'll have to set the same dimensions for both but the cprogressbar has a padding that I need to remove first

Comment: May I suggest that instead of using the progress bar libraries and animations, you can use Lottie Animation get the link at https://www.lottiefiles.com/.It is an amazing library that uses Adobe animations and I think it supports from SDK version 16 to currunt sdk versions

Comment: People, please stop giving crappy "solutions" if you don't understand how static paddings and margins would fck up your UI. This is not solution and should never be unless you just wanna have a little playground app. You simply don't know if that padding will be updated in next release by Google or not. Stop suggesting thing if you don't understand it, please

Comment: @Farid I have given two options for the question back in 2019. Kindly check it. Both solutions works as intended. As we know android keeps getting updated and some of the answers will obviously be outdated or as you say "Crappy Solutions" are the workarounds of the questions asked at a given time. Please understand that some developers just want to provide solutions at the early stages. I understand if the solution doesn't work on your problem, but since you can see it has 1 upvote means someone's problem go resolved. Please try to be supportive of at least others who are giving some answers.

Comment: If you try to be supportive on all questions then this place would be mess. "some developers just want to provide solutions at the early stages" almost no one wants that.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your progress bar code (xml file)

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

view this link :
[Android ImageButton crops on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461391/android-imagebutton-crops-on-resize)

Comment: it gives me a square and I want a circle

Comment: you can add this code to crop image in the middle of progress bar : android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: still give me a square :/

Comment: is your image a square? you can create a shape and import your image into the shape, then use "radius : 50px" for example , then your shape will be a circle, then you can replace this shape with your image in drawable property of progress bar

Comment: I tried it but the background image for the shape doesn't fit in the circle

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your round drawable, specified in

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circlebackg"
```

in the progress bar.
Find the specified drawable in res/drawable, open the xml and you'll see something like that:

```
<shape android:innerRadiusRatio="3" android:shape="ring" android:thicknessRatio="15.0" android:useLevel="true">
```

thicknessRatio="15.0" means that thickness of your circle line will be container width/15 or 0.07 * width, while innerRadiusRatio="3" means that inner radius of the circle is 0.33*width.
In order to have no padding we want to have the outer radius, which is equal to innerRadius + Thickness to be equal to half the view width, i.e

innerRadius + thickness = 0.5*width,

but in this specific case 0.07*width + 0.33*width gives us the outer radius of 0.4*width, that gives us the 0.1*width of padding.

So, to have zero padding our innerRadiusRatio (irr) and thicknessRatio (tr) must satisfy the equation:

irr + tr = irr * tr * 0.5

In my case I chose to leave the thicknessRatio = 15, thus I had to change my innerRadiusRatio to 2.3.